how to use EGL_KHR_no_config_context
my android supports EGL_KHR_no_config_context but running this throws an exception
EGLDisplay display = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
int[] version = new int[2];
EGL14.eglInitialize(display, version,0, version,0);
int[] attrib_list = {EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL14.EGL_NONE };
EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, null, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list,0);

notice null instead of config
and the exception is
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallLongMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is set to null.
at android.opengl.EGLContext android.opengl.EGL14.eglCreateContext(android.opengl.EGLDisplay, android.opengl.EGLConfig, android.opengl.EGLContext, int[], int) (EGL14.java:-2)

what is the correct way of using EGL_KHR_no_config_context

The JNI bindings don't support no-config context creation. This extension is only supported if you call EGL directly from native code.
Current Android JNI implementation always tries to retrieve a valid object handle and throws the exception in this function here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/main/core/jni/android_opengl_EGL14.cpp#105


do you know if there is something like GLSurfaceView class equivalent but written in c++ so i can copy and edit

Never tried, sorry - I tend just to write pure native (for which there are some good NDK samples in the NDK samples repository).
